# CriticalSection and Mutex locks work unexpectedly

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, winapi

I have been given the homework of making 5 threads as "philosophers" and each of them has to lock "eat" 2 synchronization locks simultaneously. Each thread must do this a million times.

The other part of this homework is to make the "philosophers" processes, and the locks mutex's.

I have made this code for the threaded part, and while it does technically work, the result isn't what I'd expect. The code has a logging system in which a red `[NUM-x]` means NUM thread attempted to lock two locks and failed to do so. And a green `[NUM1-NUM2]` means NUM1 thread successfully locked and unlocked 2 threads for the NUM2'd time.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <Windows.h>

#define CHOPSTICKS 5
#define PEOPLE 5
#define EAT_AMOUNT 1000000
#define MIN 2
#define INVALID -1
#define PAUSE printf("\n\n"); system("pause")

CRITICAL_SECTION chopsticks[CHOPSTICKS];
HANDLE chopsticksMutex[CHOPSTICKS]; // used for the mutex part of this question

VOID WINAPI eatThreadCritSect(LPVOID params) {
    int index[MIN] = { 0 };
    int usage = 0;
    BOOL usageFlag = FALSE;

    for (int i = 0; i < MIN; i++) {
        index[i] = INVALID;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < EAT_AMOUNT; i++) {
        while (usage != MIN) {
            for (int j = 0; j < CHOPSTICKS; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < MIN && !usageFlag; k++) {
                    if (index[k] == j) {
                        usageFlag = TRUE;
                    }
                }

                if (!usageFlag) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < MIN && !usageFlag; k++) {
                        if (index[k] == INVALID) {
                            if (TryEnterCriticalSection(&chopsticks[j])) {
                                index[k] = j;
                                usage++;
                            }
                            usageFlag = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                usageFlag = FALSE;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < MIN; j++) {
                if (index[j] != INVALID) {
                    LeaveCriticalSection(&chopsticks[index[j]]);
                    index[j] = INVALID;
                }
            }

            if (usage != MIN) {
                printf("\x1b[31m[%d-X]", (int)params + 1); // CHOPSTICKS UNAVAILABLE
                usage = 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\x1b[32m[%d-%d]", ((int)params + 1), i + 1); // ATE SUCCESSFULLY
        usage = 0;
    }
}

void criticalEat() {
    HANDLE hThreads[PEOPLE];

    time_t begin = time(NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++) {
        hThreads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, eatThreadCritSect, i, 0, NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++) {
        if (hThreads[i]) {
            WaitForSingleObject(hThreads[i], INFINITE);
            CloseHandle(hThreads[i]);
        }
    }
    time_t end = time(NULL);

    printf("\n\n\x1b[0mThey're now very saturated. It took them %llu seconds to eat with critical sections.", (end - begin));
}

void mutexEat() { // used for the mutex part of this question
    PROCESS_INFORMATION hProcesses[PEOPLE];
    CHAR name[] = "philosopher.exe 0";

    time_t begin = time(NULL);
    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++) {
        STARTUPINFO si;
        ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
        si.cb = sizeof(si);

        name[strlen(name) - 1] = i + '0';
        CreateProcessA("philosopher.exe", name, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &hProcesses[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < PEOPLE; i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(hProcesses[i].hProcess, INFINITE);
        CloseHandle(hProcesses[i].hThread);
        CloseHandle(hProcesses[i].hProcess);
    }

    time_t end = time(NULL);

    printf("\n\n\x1b[0mThey're now extremely fat and about to explode. It took them %llu seconds to eat with mutex's.", (end - begin));
}

int main() {
    // used for the mutex part of this question
    CHAR name[] = { "STICK_0" };
    for (int i = 0; i < CHOPSTICKS; i++) {
        name[strlen(name) - 1] = '0' + (i + 1);
        InitializeCriticalSection(&chopsticks[i]);
        chopsticksMutex[i] = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, name);
    }

    criticalEat();
    PAUSE;
    mutexEat();

    for (int i = 0; i < CHOPSTICKS; i++) {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&chopsticks[i]);
        if (chopsticksMutex[i]) { // preventing annoying warning
            CloseHandle(chopsticksMutex[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nI'm honestly surprised they made it. Why are we torturing philosophers?");
    PAUSE;
    return 0;
}
```

If I run this code, it will in a very technical sense work. However, the logged results show only green success logs, leading me to believe one of the lock checks is flawed. However, if I try to run the program in debug mode with breakpoints, and run it very slowly, red unsuccessful logs do appear. The same thing happens if I add a `Sleep(1)`. Red logs appear. I believe red logs should appear regardless of these slowing measures, since 5 threads are trying to access 5 locks at the same time, each thread taking 2 locks for themselves.

As for the mutex part, here it is:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHOPSTICKS 5
#define MIN 2
#define INVALID -1
#define EAT_AMOUNT 1000000

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    HANDLE chopsticksMutex[CHOPSTICKS];
    int index[MIN] = { 0 };
    int usage = 0;
    BOOL usageFlag = FALSE;

    CHAR name[] = { "STICK_0" };
    for (int i = 0; i < CHOPSTICKS; i++) {
        name[strlen(name) - 1] = '0' + (i + 1);
        chopsticksMutex[i] = CreateMutexA(NULL, FALSE, name);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < MIN; i++) {
        index[i] = INVALID;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < EAT_AMOUNT; i++) {
        while (usage != MIN) {
            for (int j = 0; j < CHOPSTICKS; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < MIN && !usageFlag; k++) {
                    if (index[k] == j) {
                        usageFlag = TRUE;
                    }
                }

                if (!usageFlag) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < MIN && !usageFlag; k++) {
                        if (index[k] == INVALID) {
                            if (WaitForSingleObject(chopsticksMutex[j], 0) != WAIT_ABANDONED) {
                                index[k] = j;
                                usage++;
                            }
                            usageFlag = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
                usageFlag = FALSE;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < MIN; j++) {
                if (index[j] != INVALID) {
                    ReleaseMutex(chopsticksMutex[index[j]]);
                    index[j] = INVALID;
                }
            }

            if (usage != MIN) {
                printf("\x1b[31m[%c-X]", argv[1][0] + 1); // CHOPSTICKS UNAVAILABLE
                usage = 0;
            }
        }

        printf("\x1b[32m[%c-%d]", argv[1][0], i + 1); // ATE SUCCESSFULLY
        usage = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, from what I've been taught, Mutex locks, in general, are slower. But here again, there are no red logs indicating that there was a failed attempt to lock 2 locks, and the Mutex implementation is faster, even though it makes no sense.

Does what I'm saying even make any sense? In multi-threaded programming, should I **expect** this behaviour? I'm pretty sure I should expect a couple of red logs, without intentionally bottlenecking the program.

Comment: Is this the [dining philosopher's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem)? If it is, then you may want to state this in your question and include a link to the corresponding Wikipedia article.

Comment: You don't seem to be checking the return value of `CreateMutexA` and `WaitForSingleObject` for failure. For example, if the mutex creation fails due to the name already being taken by another mutex, you will not notice. Simply assuming that all function calls succeed may lead to strange behavior of your program.

Comment: Examples of the dining philosophers problem are available at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers#C

Comment: *"if I try to run the program in debug mode with breakpoints...The same thing happens if I add a `Sleep(1)`"* Where you put the breakpoint and where you add the sleep?

Comment: I add the breakpoint anywhere in my threaded function, and `Sleep(1)` is added before releasing the locks.

Comment: @JimRogers That article is useful, but it uses the GCC standard's implementation. I'm looking for a Win32api method.

Comment: For the mutex part, what's your command line paremeters passed in? And which line output "reg log"? It seems not working for me.

Comment: In the Mutex part, line `56`. The one with the `// CHOPSTICKS UNAVAILABLE` comment. The command argument is the process's "ID" number. Usually it's given 1-5.